# How to get cell value in a GridView on LinkButton Click Event? Or RowCommand?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, datagridview

I Have a GridView which conntains multiple records and couple of Link Buttons Named Edit and Detail. Now i want to Get the Name of the User (NOT Index), when a user click on Detail Link Button. Like "Name", "FatherName" etc
Here is the .aspx code

```
<asp:GridView ID="dgvEmployeesInformation" runat="server" CssClass=" table table-bordered table-hover table-responsive" DataKeyNames="Id" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnRowCommand="dgvEmployeesInformation_RowCommand" OnRowDataBound="dgvEmployeesInformation_RowDataBound" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" OnPageIndexChanging="dgvEmployeesInformation_PageIndexChanging">
    <%--1st Column--%>
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="ID" DataField="Id" ControlStyle-BackColor="#0066ff" Visible="False">
            <ControlStyle BackColor="#0066FF"></ControlStyle>
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Name" DataField="Name" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Employee No" DataField="EmployeeNo" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Father Name" DataField="FatherName" />
        <asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="Id" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="AddEmployeeBasic1.aspx?thid={0}" HeaderText="Update" NavigateUrl="~/AddEmployeeBasic1.aspx" Text="Edit" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action" ShowHeader="True">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="lbDelete" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete"></asp:LinkButton>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lbDetail" OnClick="lbDetail_Click" DataNavigateUrlFields="Id" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="EmployeesDetails.aspx?EmpID={0}" NavigateUrl="~/EmployeesDetails.aspx" HeaderText="Show Detail" Text="Detail"></asp:LinkButton>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Here is the lbDetail_Click Code

```
protected void lbDetail_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow clickedRow = ((LinkButton)sender).NamingContainer as GridViewRow;
    Label lblUserName = (Label)clickedRow.FindControl("Name");
    EmployeeID.EmpName = lblUserName.ToString();
}
```

When i put my program on Debugging mode, the lblUserName return NULL
Here is the picture.
[image]

What i want is that, when a user click on Detail LinkButton, then on lbDetail Click event, it gets the Name of the Employee and store it in a static variable. Following is the picture
[image]

I don't understand how to solve this problem. Please help me through this. Your help will be really appreciated.

Comment: Can you please remove that `NavigateUrl` from the LinkButton. What I am thinking that it is making the page/grid control unload before it hits the event.

Comment: Actually i need `NavigateUrl` Attribute. The reason is that, that i want to navigate to another Page on the basis of Primary Key `Id`, and load all the details of corresponding Employee.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just add data attributes to the details button then get it's values at code behind.

For example:

1.) Add new data-myData='<%# Eval("Name") %>' attribute and its value to button

```
                    <asp:TemplateField>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lbDetail" OnClick="lbDetail_Click" Text="Detail" data-ID='<%# Eval("ID") %>' data-myData='<%# Eval("Name") %>' ></asp:LinkButton>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
```

2.) Get those data from event handler

```
protected void lbDetail_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     LinkButton button = (LinkButton)sender;
     var name = (string)button.Attributes["data-myData"];
     var selectedID = (string)button.Attributes["data-ID"];
     Session["selectedID"] = selectedID ;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Yeah i get that, but also i want to navigate to another page with all the information of the employee on the basis of Primary Key. They way you are telling me to do, it gets the the name and store it in the static variable but don't navigate to the page that i want to navigate. It over pass the NavigateUrl attribute. Please tell me how to do that on LinkButton Click Event. Thankyou for the information btw!

Comment: How about setting a session variable in the click event or you can add the id in querystring:

Comment: Thanks buddy. I got it. That's why I am accepting your answer. #Peace

Answer (score 1):

`lblUserName` is null because it's not a Label, but a BoundField.
What you could do it get the Cell value.

```
protected void lbDetail_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow clickedRow = ((LinkButton)sender).NamingContainer as GridViewRow;
    Label1.Text = clickedRow.Cells[1].Text;
}
```

Or use a TemplateField that does contain a Label `Name`

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="Name" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name")%>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: If you have made the `Label` control a bound one with an `ID` then I will recommend going with `FindControl()` method as it seems clear to me rather than tracking the column index.

Comment: Thanks, It gets the `Name` and stores it but then it not navigate to Another Page with all the Information. by `Response.Redirect` Method, i am able to navigate to `EmployeeDetails.aspx` Page but the `QueryString` returns `NULL`. Please help to resolve the issue.

Comment: What do you mean by `not navigate to Another Page`? And the same goes for empty `QueryString`? Maybe you want to put the value in a `Session` and do a `Response.Redirect`?

Comment: What i mean is that when a `User` click on `Details` LinkButton, then it Navigate the user to `UserDetail.aspx` with the primary key `Id`. and then on UserDetails page`Load Event`, i retrieve the data from the `Database` and populate the `DataList` control on the basis of that `Id` which comes from `Gridview` Control. Hope you got my query

Answer (score 0):

Here is how your code should look:

```
protected void lbDetail_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow clickedRow = ((LinkButton)sender).NamingContainer as GridViewRow;
    var username = clickedRow.Cells[1].Text;
    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(username))
    {
        return;
    }
    EmployeeID.EmpName = username;
}
```

Comment: Yeah i know that, but what i want is to get the name no matter what, i don't want a null value. i want a Name and store it in a static variable which i'll be using in the Details Content Page.

Comment: The above piece of code gives you a name. you can do whatever you want to do with it.